# TYPO3 add external JS without Typoscript and no access to Typo3 admin panel

Tags: javascript, php, typo3, typoscript

A new client of mine has asked to write a script (javascript) to track specific events to be reported in google analytics. The client is using TYPO3 as CMS.

Now, I know that there are a lot of answers to this question. I just wanted to know if there is any way to add an external script without using Typoscript or entering the "typo admin panel" (is this even the name?), because i do not have access at the moment.

I have more experience in wordpress, so a solution like adding a hook or even a plain script tag in, lets say the typo3 "template.php", "index.php", or whatsoever would be very nice. Does anybody know if that is possible?

Comment: Possible, but using TypoScript is the way to reference JavaScript files. Access to the backend is a requirement for administration of a TYPO3 system.

Comment: When you have access to the filesystem, you can enable the install tool and create an admin account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible. TYPO3 has a clear separation of code, configuration (`TypoScript`) and templates - unlike Wordpress which is a big mess of everything.

As written by Fabian Thommen, you could try to change one of the templates, but this depends on how the site is setup.

You can always create an admin account in the `Install Tool` as long as you have file system access to the `typo3conf/` folder.

Comment: ok, thank you so far! I have actually access to the file system. i ll check the option to create an admin account with the install tool! thank you @b263, Fabian Thommen and pgampe